# tilde expansion does not work on certain directories

Tags: bash

I found something really bizzare today - the tilde expansion does not seem to work on one of my directories.

So, I have a bunch of jpg files in a directory and I do this:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name '*.jpg' | wc -l
>>> 10000
```

but when I do this:

```
find ~+ -maxdepth 3 -type f -name '*.jpg' | wc -l
>>> 0
```

WTF!!!??

I have not encountered this before and I was wondering what is it that I have stumbled on! I have other directories and the tilde expansion works fine in all of them :(

Comment: what does `~+` mean? It seams like a bash feature as it doesn't work in `dash`

Comment: @Fravadona https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html

Comment: @Fravadona it works on all directories except 1 :(

Comment: Is the `$PWD` a real directory or a link to a directory that you followed? I get the same result if I follow a link to a dir. ... in which case `~+/` WORKS.

Comment: Can you please [edit] to show the context? Is `.` equivalent to `~` in this example? See also the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @JohnJ What's the directory name that doesn't work?

Comment: @Fravadona its just a normal dir: `.home/foo/uname/train/0`

Comment: @JamesBrown urgh - you were right - turns out the parent directory is a link URGH! can you please post it as an answer and I will accept it please? Thank you and sorry for the trouyble.

Comment: Sorry, really can't formulate that to an answer that would explain why - expect that it seems to be the way the links <s>annoy</s>work. Leave the question as is, someone will probably pick it up.

Comment: @JamesBrown yea fair. Thank you for your time anyway.. was pulling my hair (which I havent got any of) over it.

Comment: if the issue is the existence of a link then it sounds like the issue isn't with the `~+` but rather the `find` command and how it's dealing with the link; perhaps review the `find` man pages for options re: following links to see if there's a solution? or have you already come to that conclusion and found a fix? (and if so perhaps create your own answer with the solution?)

Answer (score 2):

This is an interaction between `find` and `bash`:

- `find` normally doesn't follow symbolic links
- `bash` does not canonicalise `PWD`

```
bash$ TOP=/tmp/foo
bash$ rm -rf "$TOP"
bash$ mkdir -p "$TOP"/a1/{x,y,z}
bash$ ln -s a1 "$TOP"/a2

bash$ (cd "$TOP"/a1; realpath ~+; echo $PWD ~+; find ~+;)
/tmp/foo/a1
/tmp/foo/a1 /tmp/foo/a1
/tmp/foo/a1
/tmp/foo/a1/z
/tmp/foo/a1/y
/tmp/foo/a1/x

bash$ (cd "$TOP"/a2; realpath ~+; echo $PWD ~+; find ~+;)
/tmp/foo/a1
/tmp/foo/a2 /tmp/foo/a2
/tmp/foo/a2
```

A fix is to use `find`'s [`-H`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_04) option, or append a `/`:

```
bash$ (cd "$TOP"/a2; realpath ~+; echo $PWD ~+; find -H ~+;)
/tmp/foo/a1
/tmp/foo/a2 /tmp/foo/a2
/tmp/foo/a2
/tmp/foo/a2/z
/tmp/foo/a2/y
/tmp/foo/a2/x

bash$ (cd "$TOP"/a2; realpath ~+; echo $PWD ~+; find ~+/;)
/tmp/foo/a1
/tmp/foo/a2 /tmp/foo/a2
/tmp/foo/a2/
/tmp/foo/a2/z
/tmp/foo/a2/y
/tmp/foo/a2/x
```